# JavaScript, Cannot read property 'map' of null", Nested ForEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have a script (specifically google apps script) with 3 functions gather(), getGmail() and parseEmail() ...

```html
    function gather() {
    let messages = getGmail();

    let curSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    messages.forEach(message => {curSheet.appendRow(parseEmail(message))});
    }
```

```html
function getGmail() {
const query = "label:MySummaryList NOT label:done";

let threads = GmailApp.search(query);

let label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("done");
if (!label) {label = GmailApp.createLabel("done")}

let messages = [];

threads.forEach(thread => {
    messages.push(thread.getMessages()[0].getPlainBody());
    label.addToThread(thread);
});

return messages;
}
```

```html
    function parseEmail(message){
    let parsed = message.replace(/=\n/g, '') //replace =newline with nothing
                        .split(','); //split on commas
    let result = parsed;

    return result;
    }
```

These 3 functions work great to parse 1 gmail email into a 1 spreadsheet row. The problem is the gmail I am trying to parse is a summary that needs to result in multiple spreadsheet rows.

I have this match code I want to add to function parseEmail() ...

```html
//.split(','); //split on commas   //commented out with inclusion of match code
.match(/5px">(.*?)<\/b>/g).map(function(val){return val.replace(/<\/?b>/g,'').replace(/5px">/g,'').trim();});
```

... which successfully matches the gmail message text ...

```html
5px">First text in array </b> random text 5px"> Second text in array </b>
```

... and returns an array like this ...

["First text in array", "Second text in array"]

The desired result is a spreadsheet rows like this ...
row 1 column A: First text in the array
row 2 column A: Second text in the array
... and so on for all matches captured in the array

When I add the match code to function parseEmail(), I get error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null".  I assume function gather() is expecting a single split string to append 1 spreadsheet row and now I am passing in an array resulting from the match code. Do I need a nested forEach in function gather() to loop thru the match array? Or is my approach flawed altogether?  Thanks for considering my questions!

Comment: "When I update..." is asking us to guess what the new code looks like. Why not show us the problem code and not just the working code? Secondly, how were you calling the `.match` before? Every single result? Is every result going to have a match? If no match, how are you handling that case to *not* use `.map` (`.match` returns `null` when no match)?

Comment: Thanks crashmstr, apologies for not being clear. The update is to function parseEmail(), simply commenting out the split code line and adding the match code line. Match code works standalone to properly create array of matches but full script fails when incorporated. Before I had no need for match since it was simply ingest 1 gmail email to 1 spreadsheet row. I am attempting to add match code with groups to accommodate a single summary email that needs to result in multiple spreadsheet rows when multiple matches in the array. Yes every email will have at least 1 match. Test email has 8. Thx!